# Cover entire page with layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have pretty complicated one page application, which loads abot 20 seconds.
During loaiding I would not like to show page to user.

So, I have created a layer with 100% height and 100% width, maximum z-index and position absolute. I append this layer before loading starts to the body.

```
$(loaderHTML).appendTo('body');


#mainLoader {
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(32, 35, 42);
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Layer does the job - it covers the whole page in the beginning, but then, when new elements are created on the page and height of the page becomes bigger, users see not covered elements at the bottom.

How can I make layer that covers whole page even if page changes it's height?

Comment: Tried `position:fixed`?

Comment: @EvanKnowles - it works! So simple :)

Comment: I would be careful with position fixed though, just a heads up

Comment: @vernak2539 Could you expand on that or link to what issues it could cause?

Comment: Some I've seen are overflow issues, browser compatibility (lower versions of IE), and anchor issues. Seems like these wouldn't come into play here, but when using it elsewhere, like navigation, it may cause unexpected results. Probably could have left that comment out for this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: **absolute** position doent't work, but **fixed** does. Dont't know why

```
#mainLoader { 
    z-index:1000 ; 
    width:100 %; 
    height:100 %; 
    background: rgb(32 ,35 ,42 ); 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this is a good answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#mainLoader {
    z-index: 9999;
    background: rgb(32, 35, 42);
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```